# Vim-like input for Matlab 

Tags: linux, vim, matlab

With a `.inputrc` file, I can do vim-like editing in maple. Is there a way to get vim-like line input in Matlab, either for the command-line or the GUI?

Answer (score 4):

Matlab doesn't use GNU readlines, so there's no direct way to bind vim keys to the Matlab command line through your `~/.inputrc`. You'd have to create a wrapper that captures your vim code on a line-by-line basis. [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380577/vi-input-mode-in-command-line-matlab) should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

In Matlab editor I don't know about vim-like mode.

But you can use Vim to edit files and highlight syntax:

1. you can use Vim in Windows downloading it from http://www.vim.org/download.php or using Cygwin and installing the right package. Then, to use Matlab syntax highlight, download it from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21798-editing-matlab-files-in-vim
2. you can use Emacs instead: http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2009/09/14/matlab-emacs-integration-is-back/ . There, they say that you can use Vim only changing some parameters in their solution.

Comment: I'm looking for vim-like bindings on the matlab command-line. For editing files, I'd just use `vim`.

Comment: Ya exactly... that's probably the best you will get because Matlab is not the most open program. I'm not even sure if you can write your own plugins for Matlab IDE/GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Set your bash or zsh console to vim mode using `bindkey -v`. Then install the rlwrap commmand line utility.
Then make a nice alias to start matlab with vim for it's command line.

`alias vmatlab="rlwrap -a matlab -nodesktop -nosplash"`

To start using matlab with vim at the console, in a new terminal, type `vmatlab`.

It basically works. I used vim at the matlab console. But one side effect is that it fubars tab-completion in matlab. There's a way around it using rlwrap filters, but I don't have enough knowledge about them to write one.

Answer (score 0):

A summary from the [Brushing Up Science](https://brushingupscience.wordpress.com/2018/01/19/an-improved-matlab-command-line/) post for recent versions of Matlab (R2016b or later)

To get Vim bindings for Matlab at the command line, use [IMatlab](https://github.com/imatlab/imatlab): a Jupyter kernel for Matlab.

1. Install the [Anaconda python distribution](https://conda.io/docs/download.html)
2. Install the [Matlab Engine API for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html?requestedDomain=true)
3. Install [IMatlab](https://github.com/imatlab/imatlab) itself (installation instructions at link)
4. Generate a custom config file `jupyter console --generate-config`, which will generate the file `jupyter_console_config`, likely in `~/.jupyter` (Linux/Mac) or `%PROGRAMDATA%\jupyter`
5. In the config file, uncomment/edit the line `c.ZMQTerminalInteractiveShell.editing_mode = 'vi'`
6. Matlab is then run by calling the command `jupyter console --kernel imatlab`